# Using WordPress as a backend for a Flutter App

Tags: wordpress, flutter, authentication, backend, lms

I'm going to be making a subscription-style membership website with WordPress for a friend, who is also interested in having an app built. That app, which I would build using Flutter, would need to use WordPress as a backend.

I've done a bit of research for packages that would help me link the app and the website. This seems to be the best I have found (it is from pub.dev).

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress

It says that you must use one of two authentication plugins on the WordPress site, to use the package:

- Application Passwords
- JWT Authentication for WP Rest API

The WordPress plugin I want to use, to build the membership functionality is called MemberPress. You can find it here:

https://memberpress.com/

My problem is, the Flutter packages I would need to use to link the app and the website require very specific authentication plugins, and MemberPress (or any other membership and LMS (Learning Management System) system) doesn't appear to comply with that.

Is there a way to link a MemberPress (or similar) type website with a Flutter app, or is there a way to build a WordPress tiered membership website that has LMS capabilities, linking it to a Flutter app with one of the packages available on pub.dev? I would really appreciate the advice, so thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi James, did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm looking into integrating flutter/memberpress as well.

Comment: Hi Jakob. I'd love to say that I did, but unfortunately not. It's obviously quite a niche thing, so there doesn't seem to be a lot of knowledge for it yet. I am still working on other parts of my app, although once i get to that bit, I'll let you know if I manage to figure it out, although that might not be for a few months yet.

Comment: Alright, I'll let you know as well if I get something up and running. From what I've gathered so far, the authentication used by MemberPress is just the normal WordPress authentication, so can be handled identically.

Comment: Thanks! That should be perfect then. All that I really require is a web-based interface such that people can take out a subscription and manage their subscription on the website. The Flutter app with then be able to interact with the accounts on the website, such that it can use the account details to log someone in. I know how to do it with Firebase quite easily, but this is obviously a slight step up in complication. Fingers crossed. I'll wait to hear.